# Can't read data with Retrofit to Fragment with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I try to get data from the URL and transfer it to `Fragment`. The program works but as a result, nothing is displayed. I think it is because I am using `recyclerView` doesn't correctly. I mean `recyclerView` class is good. But in `fragment` class I use `recyclwrView` incorrectly. But I don't know how to fix it.
my controller class:

```
public class Controller implements Callback<Source> {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://apisss.omt/v2/";
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Source> sources = new ArrayList<>();

    public Controller(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void start() {
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Source> news = apiInterface.getNews(API_KEY);
        news.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Source> call, Response<Source> response) {
        Source source= response.body();
        String sourceName = source.getName();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceName);
        FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        NameFragment fragmentCurrent = new NameFragment();
        fragmentCurrent.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment, fragmentCurrent);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
........
}
```

and fragment class:

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Source> sources = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(mainActivity,sources));
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            bundle.getString("sourceName");

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

method `start()` I call in `MainActivity` class
my recyclerView class:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Source> sources;
    public NewsAdapter(List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Source source = sources.get(position);
        holder.sourceName.setText(source.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sources.size();
    }

    public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView sourceName;

        public NewsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            sourceName = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you are setting argument only string value. Need to set source type array and send using putExtra and get it using getSerializableExtra. Before calling adapter need to set bundle data and pass to the adpater.